# "An error occurred while sending the order email."

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I hope someone can help me. I'm using Magento 1.9.1.0. Since yesterday my customers get no order confirmation by email. In the log file I get the following error message,

> exception 'Zend_Mail_Exception' with message 'Subject set twice' in /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/lib/Zend/Mail.php:933
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/community/Mage/Smtp/Model/Email/Template.php(40): Zend_Mail->setSubject('Laseria's Gesch...')
>
> 1 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(508): Mage_Smtp_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
>
> 2 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('11', 'general', Array, Array, Array, '1')
>
> 3 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
>
> 4 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1369): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail(true)
>
> 5 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
>
> 6 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
>
> 7 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
>
> 8 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> 9 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> 10 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 11 /is/htdocs/wp10917496_PXDL7M6OYT/www/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 12 {main}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you edit an e-mail template lately? Maybe you duplicated the subject line.

Comment: post the code that calls the email template and set its fields.